# Nested renders on react native with nested arrays

Tags: react-native

I am facing difficulty to return a render containing nested mapped arrays

```
renderData(data) {
return (
    <View>
        {
            data.map((myData, index1) => {
                return (
                    <Text key={'ev' + index1}>{myData.name}</Text>
                myData.children.map((children, index2) => {
                    return (
                        <Text key={'pi' + index2}>{children.id}</Text>
                    )
                })
            )
            })
        }
    </View>
)
}
```

It's throw me a syntax error. What is the correct way to do that ?

I also attempted to put the second function with brackets:

```
renderData(data) {
  return (
    <View>
        {
            data.map((myData, index1) => {
                return (
                    <Text key={'ev' + index1}>{myData.name}</Text>
                    {
                       myData.children.map((children, index2) => {
                        return (
                            <Text key={'pi' + index2}>{children.id}</Text>
                        )
                      })
                    }
            })
        }
    </View>
)
}
```

Comment: are your brackets all right? :D

Answer (score 0):

wrap second map function with curly brakcets

```
const renderData = data => {
return (
    <View>
    {data.map((myData, index1) => {
        return (
        <>
            <Text key={"ev" + index1}>{myData.name}</Text>
            {myData.children.map((children, index2) => {
                return <Text key={"pi" + index2}>{children.id}</Text>;
            })}
        </>
        );
    })}
    </View>
);
};
```

Comment: @MarcoJr I've updated my answer for you :) The problem was that you need to have One and only one parent element. So your aprent element in this case will be <React.Fragment> or <></>